# Is Amazon SQS a good service for syncup between two components?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I have two components - one cloud based CLS app. and the other is normal Java based admin which talks to MySQL.

Considering SQS is not FIFO and I am not sure when will I receive the message at my consumer end. Also, I might receive a new message before the previous message on same data causing data inconsistency

If I want to syncup data between these two systems, is SQS a good service ?

Is SQS generally a good tool in such sync up scenarios?

Answer (score 1):

SQS is "loosely-FIFO" and the SQS FAQ recommends adding sequencing information to each message to achieve ordering:

> If your system requires the order of messages to be preserved, place
>   sequencing information in each message so that messages can be ordered
>   when they are received. [Source](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/faqs/)

Answer (score 1):

Messages that need to arrive in a specific order may not be a good candidate for standard `SQS` queue. However you can set a message sequence counter while sending message. At receiving end, you can keep processing messages if sequence is right. In case an out of sequence message comes, wait till the right message comes and then process right sequence message and others which came in between.

[image]

On Nov 17th, 2016 [FIFO Queue](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/FIFO-queues.html) have been introduced in certain regions (`US East (Ohio)` and `US West (Oregon)`) which complements the standard queue. The order in which messages are sent and received is strictly preserved and a message is delivered once and remains available until a consumer processes and deletes it; duplicates are not introduced into the queue.
FIFO queues use the same API actions as standard queues, and the mechanics for receiving and deleting messages and changing the visibility timeout are the same. However, when sending messages, you must specify a message group ID.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Amazon SQS has just gained [FIFO Queues with Exactly-Once Processing & Deduplication](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-for-amazon-simple-queue-service-fifo-queues-with-exactly-once-delivery-deduplication/):

> Today we are making SQS even more powerful and flexible with support
>   for FIFO (first-in, first-out) queues. **We are rolling out this new
>   type of queue in two regions now**, and plan to make it available in
>   many others in early 2017.
>
> **These queues are designed to guarantee that messages are processed
>   exactly once, in the order that they are sent, and without duplicates**.
>   [...]
>
> *[emphasis mine]*

As emphasized, these new FIFO SQS queues provide more options to cover the use case at hand, but are not yet available in all [SQS regions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#sqs_region) [initially only in US East (Ohio) and US West (Oregon)]. Also, the [SQS FAQ for FIFO queues](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/faqs/#fifo-queues) outlines notable differences between standard and FIFO queues that should be considered before deciding which queue type matches a particular use case.